# How to get the height and width of text in a span not the whole span width and height

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am `HTML` like below can I get the `height` and `width` of **text only not the whole span**.

```js
var bounds = d3.select(".nodeText").node().getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(bounds.width); // 300
console.log(bounds.height); // 111
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/2.1.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: table; width: 300px; height: 111.717px;">
  <span class="nodeText" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-overflow: ellipsis; font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; color: black; opacity: 1;">Exact 765 (55.23%)</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can easily work on just the text. What i would do is: make the span/div around your text exactly fit the text size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `createRange` function.

```js
var span = d3.select(".nodeText").node();
var textNode = span.childNodes[0];

var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(textNode);

var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
var height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
var width = rect.right - rect.left;

console.log("height = "+height,"width = "+width);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/2.1.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: table; width: 50px; height: 111.717px;"><span class="nodeText" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-overflow: ellipsis; font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; color: black; opacity: 1;">Exact 765 (55.23%)</span></div>
```

Comment: Do you mean texts that are wrapped? I tried reducing the width of the span(say 50), the calculation was working fine.

Comment: What if the text is wrapped ?

Comment: Check the snippet now. I have reduced the span width. Now the text is wrapped.